# PostgreSQL: Obtain rows from table from 5 minutes ago

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to obtain from the following example table all the rows that match the exactly 5 minutes ago since the query is run.

The query will be scheduled to run every 5 minutes to get all the rows that were created in that range of time.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    id numeric(8)
)
```

I've tried with the interval option but because my table has the column defined as `timestamp without time zone` I'm not getting the proper info that I need.

Comment: (1) Having a column named `date` is a bad idea as that's a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and will just lead to an eternity of ugly quoting. (2) Calling a `timestamp` column a "date" is a strange thing to do.

Comment: And your `id` (which should really be `mytable_id` or something descriptive) should probably be an `integer` or `bigint` column.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Not sure why `INTERVAL` is not working:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE "date" >= NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE "date_column_name" >= NOW() - INTERVAL '5 minutes';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).